# Index file conflict with include files

Tags: php, html, css, include

I have a problem with my `index.php` together with my "include files". My `index.php` file is located inside the main folder named `mysite` and the rest inside it are `subfolders` with the respective .php files. The sub-folder files are working perfectly, except the `index.php`. The include files are messed up every  time I preview it in the browser.

The path for the `index.php` file goes like this:

```
mysite/index.php
```

The path for the `include files` goes like this:

```
mysite/pages/include/header.php
```

Here is the HTML file with the include files:

```
<html>
   <head>

   <?php 
   include ("pages/include/headertop.php");
   include ("pages/include/header.php");
   include ("pages/include/nav.php"); 
   ?>

   </head>
</html>
```

Kindly correct me if I have missed something here.

By the way, I'm using XAMPP.

Thank you and More power!

Answer (score 0):

edit your index.php:

```
include ("../pages/include/headertop.php");
include ("../pages/include/header.php");
include ("../pages/include/nav.php");
```

and try again "mysite/index.php"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that you are calling these include commands in a .php file and not .html file.
Secondly make sure that your server is up and running well.
After this try this code:

```
<html>
   <head>

   <?php 
   include "pages/include/headertop.php";
   include "pages/include/header.php";
   include "pages/include/nav.php"; 
   ?>

   </head>
</html>
```

P.S: just remove the brackets from include.
Please also make sure that the file names are correct and they follow the proper case.